# docker - How to set up environment database for docker-compose.yml file from env.ini file outide?

Tags: python, django, docker

This is my `docker-compose.yml` which I hard-code the information of database,

I want to input in it from a file `env.ini` of mine before pushing it to GitLab for safety but dont know how to do it.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=#######                     Hide these information and take it from
      - POSTGRES_USER=#####                     another file when running it
      - POSTGRES_HOST=172#####
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=#########
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Plus: my file `env.ini` is quite complicated since its contains a lot of others information, it looks like this:

```
[sv_info]
host = #########
user = ########
password = ########
database = #
venus_base_url = #################
venus_auth_key =
cargo_base_url = #################
cargo_awb_acckey = #################
cargo_awb_cusnum = #################
cargo_awb_user = #################
cargo_awb_revkey = #################

[heremap_info]
url = #################
api_key = #################
```

Usually, I use `from configparser import ConfigParser` in `Python` to work with this `env.ini` in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your file with environment variable should be named `.env` and it's content would be like the following:

```
POSTGRES_DB=cookies
POSTGRES_USER=jamie
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=oliver
POSTGRES_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

Those environment variables should be passed to containers. To achieve that, you should update docker compose config as follows:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

And then in your django settings:

```py
import os


# ...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['POSTGRES_DB'],
        'USER': os.environ['POSTGRES_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['POSTGRES_HOST'],
        'PORT': 5432,
    },
}
```

I also highly recommend to use [environs](https://pypi.org/project/environs/) package to read values of environment variables.

```py
from environs import Env


env = Env()
IS_ENABLED = env.bool('IS_ENABLED', default=True)
```

That means, even when environment variable `IS_ENABLED` value is `True` (string) - `environs` will convert it to `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

- add a file settings.ini.template like:

```
[default]
username=@@USERNAME@@
password=@@PASSWORD@@
```

- Add this to the repository.
- Add variables `THE_USERNAME` and `THE_PASSWORD` in your project.

Now in `gitlab-ci.yml` on this section `before_script` do:

```
sed -e 's/@@USERNAME@@/'$THE_USERNAME'/' -e 's/@@PASSWORD@@/'$THE_PASSWORD'/' settings.ini.template > settings.ini.
```

Comment: check this for more https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-pass-ini-secure-details-to-gitlab-runner-to-run-test/19636